# Panels in Dynamic Workload Console are not displayed correctly in Internet Explorer 8 and 9

Tags: internet-explorer, dynamic, console, workload-scheduler, workload

with Internet Explorer version 8 or 9, some panels in Dynamic Workload Console, are not displayed well. For example:

- The Graphical View or some Dashboard graphics are not displayed correctly.
- When duplicating a Monitor task, the entire Dashboard Application Services navigation toolbar appears duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with incorrect settings in Internet Explorer. To avoid or limit this behaviour, use the following workarounds:

•Add the Dynamic Workload Console web site to the Local intranet security zone of Internet Explorer, with its default security level.

•Add the hostname of the Dynamic Workload Console to the web sites used in compatibility View by Internet Explorer. To do it, from Internet Explorer toolbar, click Tools > Compatibility View Settings and add the Dynamic Workload Console hostname to the list.

•Turn off Internet Explorer Enhanced Security mode as described in the following documentation: IBM Tivoli Security Information and Event Manager, section about Disabling Enhanced Security Configuration. In fact, Dashboard Application Services Hub does not support Internet Explorer with Enhanced Security mode active.